# write OMNET++ output to a text file

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

Greeting All,

I have two questions regarding OMNET++ output results

1- I have a simulation that uses AODV routing protocol in VANET network, but
when I record pcap for this simulation, it's shown as corrupted or damage even when I spill it to multi pcap file. How can I solve that? is the Inet pcap support AODV?

2-Is there a way to write this output (in below pic) to a text file or exported as excel format (I highlighted with red color).
I need all the information (event #, time, Relevant hop, name, info). I can copy it but it takes a time when I have around 10000 events?

[image: OMNET output]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you should be able to record the information you want with the  statistics methods provided by OMNeT++. You should refer to `cOutVector` for real-time data recording. **Statistical Collection** are well explained in Part. 5 of the OMNeT++ TicToc Tutorial [1](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part5/).

Once you have recorded your data, you can export them from the **Browse Data** interface (select the vectors you previously recorded in the browse data tab, right click and select **Export Data**).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used and export the vectors but it contains a statistics only (i need to get which node or module sent ordered by time like what I highlighted in the pic or what I can get it from pcap file).

Comment: If you just want to store the highlighted information in a text file or excel file at the end of the simulation, you can simply copy paste them.